# Getting NoClassDefFoundError while running PMD task from Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, pmd

I am getting `NoClassDefFoundError` while running PMD task via Gradle.

I am having `pmd-5.1.1.jar`, `commons-io-1.4.jar` as well as all the other `jars` in `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` directory. My java files are in the directory `src\com\company\project`

**Gradle Build file**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'pmd'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
webAppDirName = 'WebContent'

repositories {
  flatDir { dirs "WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" }
}
dependencies {
    providedCompile fileTree(dir: "WebContent/WEB-INF/lib", include: '*.jar')   
}
war {
    archiveName "ROOT.war"
}
```

**Error Log**

```
C:\MyWorkspace\MyProject>gradle build
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:war UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:pmdMain FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':pmdMain'.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.275 secs
```

This is the first time I am trying Gradle. I am able to build as well as generate WAR but PMD is failing me. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last found the issue. I needed to resolve pmd and all it's transitive dependencies from a remote repo like Maven Central.

```
repositories {  
    mavenCentral()  
}

pmd {
toolVersion = "5.1.1"
ignoreFailures = true
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. You shouldn't put dependencies under `WEB-INF/lib`.

Answer (score 1):

I know that You've already found the answer but FYI I'm adding solution to the problem.

Basically You have non standard project structure. First of all, web content should be placed under `src/main/webapp` (sources under `src/main/java` and so on). Secondly You should not put diagnostics tools (*pmd*) under `WEB-INF/lib`. There's no need to have this jars deployed along with the whole application to the application server.

There was also no declaration of maven repo, so the dependencies could not be resolved (*commons-io*, *asm*, *jaxen*, etc.) and the were missing dependencies under *pmd* classpath (*commons-io*, etc.) - note the *pmd* scope in *dependencies* block.

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/27720151) you can find two projects - with standard and non-standard project layout. Both are configured correctly.